# Calculating Median in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: count, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, median

I need to calculate Median for several fields in a query and group it by one of the column.  Is there a way to calculate Median easily in SQL Server 2008 R2?  I am having trouble calculating it in 2008 R2.

```
Table structure:
PatientName (need to calculate count group by PatientType)
PatientType (should be used to group the query by),
minutes1,
minutes2,
minutes3,
minutes4,
minutes5

End Result:
PatientCount (Group by PatientType),
Median For minutes1 (Group by PatientType),
Median For minutes2 (Group by PatientType),
Median For minutes3 (Group by PatientType),
Median For minutes4 (Group by PatientType),
Median For minutes5 (Group by PatientType)
```

Comment: Easily, no.  But it can be done.  You could use PERCENTILE_DISC, but that wasn't available until 2012.  Even then I'm not sure if that is a true median or uses the nearest smaller value in even sets. For example, given the values `1,3,5,7` is the median is 4, but would 3 be close enough for you?

Comment: In past, I've used PERCENTILE_DISC or PERCENTILE_CONT, but they're only useful when it is 2012 or above.  Also, I need a true median.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT PatientType, minutes1=(
  SELECT AVG(1.0 * minutes1)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t3.minutes1, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t3.minutes1), c.c
    FROM (SELECT minutes1 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t3
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT minutes1 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t4) AS c
  ) AS x
  WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2)
), minutes2=(
  SELECT AVG(1.0 * minutes2)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t3.minutes2, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t3.minutes1), c.c
    FROM (SELECT minutes2 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t3
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT minutes2 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t4) AS c
  ) AS x
  WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2)
), minutes3=(
  SELECT AVG(1.0 * minutes1)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t3.minutes3, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t3.minutes1), c.c
    FROM (SELECT minutes3 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t3
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT minutes3 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t4) AS c
  ) AS x
  WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2)
), minutes4=(
  SELECT AVG(1.0 * minutes4)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t3.minutes1, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t3.minutes1), c.c
    FROM (SELECT minutes4 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t3
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT minutes4 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t4) AS c
  ) AS x
  WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2)
), minutes5=(
  SELECT AVG(1.0 * minutes5)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t3.minutes1, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t3.minutes1), c.c
    FROM (SELECT minutes5 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t3
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT minutes5 FROM Table t2 WHERE t1.PatientType=t2.PatientType) t4) AS c
  ) AS x
  WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2)
)
FROM Table t1
GROUP BY PatientType
```

and there is probably a much better way, and it could likely be optimized quite a bit.

Comment: What if I these fields have nulls?  Would you suggest replacing nulls with 0 or not taking them into my calculation when calculating median?

Comment: I would expect that nulls would not be taken account when calculating median, but that is entirely up to what your nulls mean in the database.